# MySQL UPDATE doesn't change anything

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update a database entry but it won't change anything. I'm getting no errors which confuses me...

Code:

```
if(isset($_GET['edit']))
{
    $idn = $_GET['id'];
    $namn = $_POST['namn'];
    $adress = $_POST['adress'];
    $postnummer = $_POST['postnummer'];
    $postort = $_POST['postort'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $status = 0;
    echo $namn;
    $sql="UPDATE ordrar SET namn = '$namn' AND adress = '$adress' AND postnummer = '$postnummer'
    AND postort = '$postort' AND email = '$email' AND status = '$status' WHERE id = '$idn'";
    if (!mysql_query($sql))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    //$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    //header('Location:'. $referer);
}
```

Thanks for answers
/Victor

Comment: Did you capture $sql and run it directly against the database to verify an update occurred?

Comment: Did you spell "address" correctly?

Comment: @amphetamachine if not it will throw an error. Go figure.

Comment: do you have have $_GET['edit'] varibale set?

Comment: Col. Shrapnel, this question have already been answered... Everything works now.

Comment: No, it isn't. The question is why don't you see an error message for the erroneous query.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your immediate problem is SQL syntax. Read the [documentation on UPDATES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html) and replace the ANDs with commas.

Your secondary, but possibly larger problem is that you're building a query out of untrusted user input. That's a recipe for a SQL injection attack. Use bind variables instead.

Comment: Yeah, my own sanitize function is removed cause I tought that was the problem. First paragraph worked it out :) Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Ref [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-update-query.htm)

Syntax for Update

```
UPDATE table_name SET field1=new-value1, field2=new-value2 [WHERE Clause]
```

Your query should

```
 $sql="UPDATE ordrar SET namn = '$namn' , adress = '$adress' ,
          postnummer = '$postnummer' , postort = '$postort' , email = '$email' ,
          status = '$status' WHERE id = '$idn'";
```

Answer (score -4):

if you get no errors it does mean that no records matched WHERE condition

or you're probably don't have $_GET['edit'] varibale set

Comment: and i've told you already that AND syntax is wrong AND I'm an oafish brute.

Comment: @Victor IN YOUR OTHER QUESTION! where you have accepted the same incorrect answer.

Comment: I've saw that now, sorry for that but the error disappeared when I used that code but now I saw that you're answer was the correct one.